# How to search with partial exact match in Django

Tags: django, filter, model

Table definition:

```
class Hello(models.Model):
  name models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True)
```

2 records are in db:

```
#1 aaaa-bbbb (cd)
#2  aaa-bbbb (cef)
```

The search key word: 'aaa-bbbb', or 'aaa-bbbb (c',

```
ret = models.Hello.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains='aaa-bbbb'))
```

Expected result is #2, but 2 records are found.

How to find #2?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `icontains` use `iexact` like this:

```
ret = models.Hello.objects.filter(name__iexact='aaa-bbbb')
```

You don't need to use `Q` if you are filtering through only one field

Comment: iexact will not return any record, right? Tried, not work as 0 record returned. icontains return 2 records.

Comment: It should return if name fileld in your model has the exact value with your provided value @user3792705.`iexact` is a case insensitive match

Comment: Field name (db record) length > key word (user entered) length. That's the reason why this question is raised. The solution does not work, as it returns 0 record. It does not find any record.

Comment: Thought again. May be this is fuzzy match question. #2 is more likely to match the key word.

Comment: The 2 keywords provided are not able to uniquely identify #2 record. 'aaa-bbbb (ce' has to be provided to identify the keyword. I think the question asked is not correct.